# How to find word with the greatest number of repeated letters

Tags: ruby

My goal is to find the word with greatest number of repeated letters in a given string. For example, `"aabcc ddeeteefef iijjfff"` would return `"ddeeteefef"` because `"e"` is repeated five times in this word and that is more than all other repeating characters.

So far this is what I got, but it has many problems and is not complete:

```
def LetterCountI(str)
  s = str.split(" ")
  i = 0
  result = []
  t = s[i].scan(/((.)\2+)/).map(&:max) 
  u = t.max { |a, b| a.length <=> b.length }
  return u.split(//).count 
end
```

The code I have only finds consecutive patterns; if the pattern is interrupted (such as with `"aabaaa"`, it counts a three times instead of five).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
s = "aabcc ddeeteefef iijjfff" 
# intermediate calculation that's happening in the final code
s.split(" ").map { |w| w.chars.max_by { |e| w.count(e) } }
# => ["a", "e", "f"] # getting the max count character from each word
s.split(" ").map { |w| w.count(w.chars.max_by { |e| w.count(e) }) }
# => [2, 5, 3] # getting the max count character's count from each word
# final code
s.split(" ").max_by { |w| w.count(w.chars.max_by { |e| w.count(e) }) }
# => "ddeeteefef"
```

**update**

`each_with_object` gives better result than `group_by` method.

```
require 'benchmark'

s = "aabcc ddeeteefef iijjfff" 

def phrogz(s)
   s.scan(/\w+/).max_by{ |word| word.chars.group_by(&:to_s).values.map(&:size).max }
end

def arup_v1(s)
    max_string = s.split.max_by do |w| 
       h = w.chars.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |e,hsh|
         hsh[e] += 1
       end
       h.values.max
    end
end

def arup_v2(s)
   s.split.max_by { |w| w.count(w.chars.max_by { |e| w.count(e) }) }
end

n = 100_000
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("Phrogz:") { n.times {|i| phrogz s } }
  x.report("arup_v2:"){ n.times {|i| arup_v2 s } }
  x.report("arup_v1:"){ n.times {|i| arup_v1 s } }
end
```

*output*

```
            user     system      total        real
Phrogz:   1.981000   0.000000   1.981000 (  1.979198)
arup_v2:  0.874000   0.000000   0.874000 (  0.878088)
arup_v1:  1.684000   0.000000   1.684000 (  1.685168)
```

Comment: Could you add more information about how this code works? I'm curious.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis added..hope it helps :)

Comment: Note that while my answer is not as efficient as it could be, this answer is particularly algorithmically bad. It's well-explained, and effective for short strings, but using `word.chars{ |char| word.count(char) }` results in O(n^2) performance as your string grows.

Comment: @Phrogz Any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: @Phrogz `each_with_object` gives better result than `group_by` method.

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to be less clever while improving speed. If absolute speed is a requirement we could investigate micro optimizations.

Comment: @Phrogz No debate! I thought I should notify you with the latest update, thus did the same.  :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit I thank you for it. And, it seems I was wrong. I don't know why your version is not behaving O(n^2), but I was unable to make it behave badly using even unreasonably long 'words'. As always, testing beats theory. :)

Comment: @Arup Rakshit Thanks for helping, indeed your solution works!

Comment: @Stephens Its fastest too.. :)

Comment: @Abdo Yes, I will go for it.

Comment: Great work here! Hard to find something better but I'm working on it :-) (+1)

Answer (score 6):

```
str.scan(/\w+/).max_by{ |w| w.chars.group_by(&:to_s).values.map(&:size).max }
```

- `scan(/\w+/)` — create an array of all sequences of 'word' characters
- `max_by{ … }` — find the word that gives the largest value inside this block
- `chars` — split the string into characters
- `group_by(&:to_s)` — create a hash mapping each character to an array of all the occurrences
- `values` — just get all the arrays of the occurrences
- `map(&:size)` — convert each array to the number of characters in that array
- `max` — find the largest characters and use this as the result for `max_by` to examine

**Edit**: Written less compactly:

```
str.scan(/\w+/).max_by do |word|
  word.chars
      .group_by{ |char| char }
      .map{ |char,array| array.size }
      .max
end
```

Written less functionally and with less Ruby-isms (to make it look more like "other" languages):

```
words_by_most_repeated = []
str.split(" ").each do |word|
  count_by_char = {} # hash mapping character to count of occurrences
  word.chars.each do |char|
    count_by_char[ char ] = 0 unless count_by_char[ char ]
    count_by_char[ char ] += 1
  end
  maximum_count = 0
  count_by_char.each do |char,count|
    if count > maximum_count then
      maximum_count = count
    end
  end
  words_by_most_repeated[ maximum_count ] = word
end

most_repeated = words_by_most_repeated.last
```

Comment: My answer was stupid. `group_by` then `values`, as in your answer is better.

Comment: @sawa I dunno, I like your usage of `chunk`; I don't often get to see it.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Ruby code, but is this what all Ruby code looks like? It seems so alien compared to any other language I've seen

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis It doesn't have to be. See my edit. One of Ruby's best characteristics is its use of "blocks", which are a very easy syntax for passing a lambda closure to a method. Where JavaScript has `myArray.forEach(function(el){ doSomethingWith(el) }` Ruby instead has `my_array.each{ |el| do_something_with(el) }`. For the common case of "invoke the method 'foo' on each object supplied to the method you can use the convenient-but-line-noise syntax `my_array.each(&:foo)`. Combined with functional programming as I used above and method invocations that don't need parens and it does look odd.

Comment: @Phrogz Your code works perfectly, the group_by and max_by methods are key to solving this issue. I really appreciate such detailed answer and explanation. I've learned a lot from your code here! Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Similar to sawa's answer:

```
"aabcc ddeeteefef iijjfff".split.max_by{|w| w.length - w.chars.uniq.length}
=> "ddeeteefef"
```

In Ruby 2.x, this works as-is because `String#chars` returns an array.  In earlier versions of ruby, `String#chars` yields an enumerator so you need to add `.to_a` before applying `uniq`. I did my testing in Ruby 2.0, and overlooked this until it was pointed out by Stephens.

I believe this is valid, since the question was "greatest number of repeated letters in a given string" rather than greatest number of repeats for a single letter in a given string.

Comment: @Phrogz Thanks, but it's even better if I omit the sort - `uniq` works it out all by itself.

Comment: I think this is wrong compared to the example in the question (separate from the wording of the question) but still quite nice.

Comment: @Phrogz I think it's consistent with the question's wording, but the wording is ambiguous. Stephens could weigh in here as to whether this is what was intended.

Comment: @pjs wow this is indeed very smart and intuitive. This one works as intended. Only that I believe a small part is missing. in the block it should be { |w| w.length - w.chars.to_a.uniq.length }              if you don't put .to_a after .chars I believe it will return #enum error message

Comment: @Stephens I'm confused. Which of the following is "longest": "aabbcc" or "eeel"? My answer says "eeel", while this answer says "aabbcc".

Comment: @Phrogz: I would expect it to be "aabbcc", because it has three letters that are repeats, while "eeel" only has two.

Comment: @Phrogz "eeel" is longer than "aabbcc". Ah...thanks for pointing out, you're right, I didn't test it with enough sample data set. Although the algo in this code is smart but it ultimately returned the wrong answer.

Comment: @pjs sorry I think maybe it's my wording in the question that confused you, your code is still brilliant for the way you interpreted the problem. Using Phrogz's example, "eeel" should come before "aabbcc" because "e" repeated three times in eeel while "a/b/c" only repeated twice in "aabbcc"

Comment: @Stephens Fair enough, that's why I asked for clarification earlier.  So what you're looking for is the word that has the greatest number of repeats for any **single** character rather than the word with the greatest number of repeated letters.

Answer (score 2):

```
"aabcc ddeeteefef iijjfff"
.split.max_by{|w| w.chars.sort.chunk{|e| e}.map{|e| e.last.length}.max}
# => "ddeeteefef"
```

Comment: +1 for the use of argumentless `split`. I use `(&:to_s)` instead of `{|e| e}` for strings, but I do wish Ruby had an `Object#me` method that returned the object for these cases.

Comment: @Phrogz Matz seemed to have accepted a proposal to name such method `itself` https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6373.

Comment: Oh? That's good to know (but frustratingly long for golfing. :)

Comment: @sawa Works! and thanks for helping, this is the first time I've ever used the .chunk method in Ruby! Definitely interesting