# How many Mondays are in an interval of time in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two `DateTime` objects (`date0` and `date1`).

I want to know how many **Mondays** are between `[date0..date1]`

What is the best way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it differently, using [`Date#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-upto) and [`Array#count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-count) :

```
require 'date'

date1 = Date.parse "01/01/2014"
date2 = Date.parse "01/03/2014"

date1.upto(date2).count(&:monday?) # => 8
```

Comment: @Abdo You beat my simplicity, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21694402/2767755).

Comment: Hahah.. I'll work on it! Btw, a trick I learned from you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21714607/226255

Answer (score 5):

Use [Date#monday?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-monday-3F)

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'date'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> date1 = "01/01/2014"
=> "01/01/2014"
[3] pry(main)> date2 = "01/03/2014"
=> "01/03/2014"
(Date.parse(date1)..Date.parse(date2)).select { |x| x.monday? }
=> [#<Date: 2014-01-06 ((2456664j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-01-13 ((2456671j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-01-20 ((2456678j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-01-27 ((2456685j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-02-03 ((2456692j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-02-10 ((2456699j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-02-17 ((2456706j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
 #<Date: 2014-02-24 ((2456713j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
```

### EDIT

The above gives the list of Mondays as date objects but if you need their count then it is:

```
mondays = (Date.parse(date1)..Date.parse(date2)).select { |x| x.monday? }
mondays.count
=> 8
```

[Array#count](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-count)

For `DateTime` logic remains same

```
[10] pry(main)> date1 = "01/01/2014"
=> "01/01/2014"
[11] pry(main)> date2 = "01/03/2014"
=> "01/03/2014"
[12] pry(main)> (DateTime.parse(date1)..DateTime.parse(date2)).select { |x| x.monday? }.size
=> 8
```

Comment: I think you really want .count{ |X| x.monday?} not select, to answer the OP's question

Comment: @Jazzepi counting is trivial when you get the list

Comment: Obviously, but that's not what OP asked.

Comment: @Jazzepi I have included that to answer his question in all completeness :)

Comment: You don't seem to get Jazzepi's point. You can do it in one line by using `count` instead of `select`: `(Date.parse(date1)..Date.parse(date2)).count { |x| x.monday? }` You don't need `.select`!

Comment: @Mischa I do get his point, I consider it trivial either way, I have helped the OP with the solution it is left to him to do what he wants with it, and in most situations he might still need the `DateTime` objects, so why not "eat your cake and have it", getting the dates and also getting the count

Comment: @Mischa any benchmark to show which is faster?? `count` on an existing list is always `O(1)` except of course you can convince me that `(Date.parse(date1)..Date.parse(date2)).count { |x| x.monday? }` is faster than `(Date.parse(date1)..Date.parse(date2)).select { |x| x.monday? }`, and I have basically saved the OP the need to comeback asking for how to get the `DateTime` objects either way

Comment: @Mischa I gave him a combo for the price of one :)

Comment: @Jazzepi I agreed with you.

Answer (score 5):

@Matt showed a O(1) solution, here's my re-implementation with a little more explanation:

Basically, in order to get the number of mondays (or any other day) between two dates, we want to count the number of weeks from the start_date till the end_date and get rid of a couple exceptions (I'll explain below).

*Img0: Days of the week, 0 denoting Sunday.*

[image]

Getting the number of weeks is similar to getting the number of rows in the table above. The only difference is that we'll have an offset, which is start_date's wday.

```
number_of_rows = (day_diff + start_date.wday) / 7 + 1
```

We add 1 because given two valid dates, the minimum number of rows is 1.

Next, if our start_date's wday is greater than the day of week (dow in code), we don't want to count that monday in the row, thus the -1. (check Img0 for illustration - the blue area is an interval of days that starts after a monday and ends before the following monday)

Likewise, if the end_date's wday is less than the day of week, we don't want to count the monday in the row.

```
def day_count(dow, start_date, end_date)
  day_diff = (end_date - start_date).to_i
  number_of_rows = (day_diff + start_date.wday) / 7 + 1
  end_day_index = (day_diff + start_date.wday) % 7
  # could have done end_date.wday ; using % 7 to explain
  # its existence in @Matt's code

  number_of_rows + 
       ( start_date.wday > dow ? -1 : 0 ) + 
       ( end_day_index < dow  ? -1 : 0)

end

def monday_count(start_date, end_date)
  day_count(1, start_date, end_date)
end
```

Comment: Oh!! What an effort. Like it. It seems sometimes, Ruby way is not a good idea! :)

Comment: Haha! Ruby is a great idea (your solution took 1.7s counting mondays from 8000BC till today) but @Matt knows how to get me to waste an hour  to figure out what he's doing :-)

Comment: It seems, you know *algorithm and programming*, where i have only the *later* one. :(

Comment: You're ridiculous! You have the most creative and simplest Ruby solutions out there! This problem should be tackled the way you did since simplicity trumps effectiveness in a problem like this.
I'm sure if something requires efficiency (which is not the case for most problems we see here), you are fully capable of implementing a great algorithm for it :-)

Answer (score 2):

O(1) solution:

```
require 'date'
(1 + (date1-date0).to_i + (date0.wday+5) % 7) / 7
```

Comment: I think this deserves an explanation. What for example if I want to count Tuesdays?

Comment: Brilliant solution but you should be awarded the worst code on SO badge! (+1)

Comment: @toro2k I just attempted an explanation (answer) with a simpler implementation (without Matt's factorization of %7 and usage of 5 to remove if conditions)

Comment: You're right this does deserve an explanation which I have been thinking about. When I come up with one I'll update this answer. In the meantime, it was just intuition that it should be of the form `(ndays + (date0.wday+x)%7)/7` and so it is adjusting for `x`. For Tuesdays, replace 5 with 4. Generally replace 5 with `6-d` where `d` is the day of the week to count.

Answer (score 1):

```
 my_days = [1] # day of the week in 0-6. Sunday is day-of-week 0; Saturday is day-of-week 6.
 result = (date0..date1).to_a.select {|k| my_days.include?(k.wday)}
```